# Crossfilter DC.JS Chart on Sub Elements

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Here is the sample data:

```
var payments = crossfilter([
      {date: "2011-11-14T16:17:54Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab", productIDs:["001"], coupons:["coupon 1"]},
      {date: "2011-11-14T16:20:19Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab", productIDs:["001", "005"], coupons:["coupon 1"]},
      {date: "2011-11-14T16:28:54Z", quantity: 1, total: 300, tip: 200, type: "visa", productIDs:["004" ,"005"], coupons:["coupon 2"]},
      {date: "2011-11-14T16:30:43Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab", productIDs:["001", "002"], coupons:["coupon 1", "coupon 2"]},
      {date: "2011-11-14T16:48:46Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab", productIDs:["005"], coupons:["coupon 1"]},
      {date: "2011-11-14T16:53:41Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab", productIDs:["001", "004" ,"005"], coupons:["coupon 1", "coupon 2"]},
      {date: "2011-11-14T16:54:06Z", quantity: 1, total: 100, tip: 0, type: "cash", productIDs:["001", "002", "003", "004" ,"005"], coupons:["coupon 2"]},
      {date: "2011-11-14T16:58:03Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab", productIDs:["001"], coupons:["coupon 1", "coupon 2"]},
      {date: "2011-11-14T17:07:21Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab", productIDs:["004" ,"005"], coupons:["coupon 1", "coupon 2"]},
      {date: "2011-11-14T17:22:59Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab", productIDs:["001", "002", "004" ,"005"], coupons:["coupon 1", "coupon 2"]},
      {date: "2011-11-14T17:25:45Z", quantity: 2, total: 200, tip: 0, type: "cash", productIDs:["002"], coupons:["coupon 1", "coupon 2"]},
      {date: "2011-11-14T17:29:52Z", quantity: 1, total: 200, tip: 100, type: "visa", productIDs:["004"], coupons:["coupon 1", "coupon 2"]}
]);
```

I would like to have two bar charts, one by the ProduceIDs, and another by Coupons, so the chart will be based on the aggregated data like

```
ProductID    Total
001          5
002          6
003          4
004          8

Coupon       Total
coupon 1     2
coupon 2     5
```

Also also be able to click on a slice in Product Pie and have the Coupon pie updated.

I couldn't find any example that will allow me to do that.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe "tag dimensions" aka array-based keys? https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_with_arrays

Comment: Obligatory disclaimer: don't use tag dimensions in any place where you expect everything to add up to 100% (or your chart [makes it look like they would](https://www.nbcchicago.com/news/local/FOX-News-Chart-Fails-Math-73711092.html)).

Comment: Thanks Gordon! That is exactly what I needed and totally understand about the disclaimer :)